# PHP: Create a Mac executable

Tags: php, macos, chmod

I created a project years ago that allows a user to type in the IP address of a printer, select the printer model click submit and it would create a mac executable that would automatically install the print driver on the computer.

Unfortunately, I didn't back up the code and it's lost in the ether.

I need to rebuild this project and the only part I'm stuck on is making the file an executable for Macs.

On a mac, all I need to do is open up Terminal and type the following command to make it executable:

```
 chmod +x filename
```

How do i do this in PHP?

Here's what i've attempted so far

```
$file = fopen("installer", "w+") or die("file not open");

$kyocerascript = 'code for the script goes here';


fwrite($file,$kyocerascript) or die("Data not write");


fclose($file);
chmod("installer", "+x");
```

and i've tried

```
chmod($file, "+x");
```

My code creates the file without any issues but it's not an executable.

***I resolved this issue by zipping the file***

Comment: Perhaps you have a permission issue here. Is the PHP script running under a user that is permitted to make changes on the file?

Comment: Its not a permission issue. I think i'll need to zip the file in order to keep the extension. I just uploaded an exectuable to my server, redownloaded it and the extension is gone.

Comment: What extension are you meaning? The filename you show has no extension.

Answer (score -2):

To execute php at any type of machine you need to install php itself. You can install one of many "local servers" like: XAMPP, WAMP, etc.